# Error bar in QT

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qtcharts

I am trying to create Error bar in QT using Box and Whiskers. I get the following plot:

[image]

But desired is something like this

[image: Image2]

Code for box i used is:

```
QBoxSet *box = new QBoxSet(0);
box->setValue(QBoxSet::LowerExtreme, min);
box->setValue(QBoxSet::UpperExtreme, max);
box->setValue(QBoxSet::LowerQuartile,fres);
```

The `QBoxSet::LowerExtreme` is behind the box, how I can move it on top of the box? or is there any other method to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using QBoxSet::Median?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, it just creates a horizontal line. No connection to the upper part.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do it.  The way QtCharts is written is made almost impossible to customize. So you are pretty much stuck with what you have. Or you could try other plotting library like QCustomPlot or qwt.